# random data generation for Uniform Distribution for Set of Parameter Vector

Tags: r

I am interested in generating a data from uniform distribution using a vector of parameter (say parameter vector of size 10). I tried in R software but error is there. Please see the below code, it gives only one observation but I am interested to get all the 10 values.

```
parameter=c(1,2,4,5,3,45,10,14,7,12)
runif(1,0,parameter)
```

Comment: What error do you get? You intend the parameter to be the upper bound of the uniform distribution? It's unclear whether you're trying to generate one random number from the interval (0, parameter), or where the idea of generating 10 values would come from

Answer (score 2):

```
runif(10,0,parameter)
```

Or if you want it to automatically detect how many values to generate based on the length...

```
runif(length(parameter), 0, parameter)
```